# Mobile friendly CSS tab functionality

Tags: html, css

I have successfully from examples created an CSS only tab functionality. The code works perfect on a pc screen, but on mobile the tabs go below each other and then they can't be pressed.

My CSS knowledge is limited to fix the problem. There is an "position: absolute;" div inside an  "position: relative;" container.

If anyone can help change the code so the functionality can be affective on mobile also.

CSS for tab functionality.

```
.wietabs {
    position: relative;   
    min-height: 600px; 
    clear: both;
    margin: 25px 0;
}
.wietab {
    float: left;
}
.wietab label {
    background: #eee; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    margin-left: -1px; 
    position: relative;
    left: 1px; 
    display: inline;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
.wietab [type=radio] {
    display: none;   
}
.wietabcontent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    overflow: auto;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .wietabcontent {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML for tab functionality

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div style="min-height: 300px;" class="wietabs">
        <div class="wietab">
            <input type="radio" id="wietab-1" name="wietab-group-1" checked>
            <label for="wietab-1">Tab1 Content</label>
            <div class="wietabcontent">
                <p>
                    Tab1          
                </p>
            </div> 
        </div>

        <div class="wietab">
            <input type="radio" id="wietab-2" name="wietab-group-1">
            <label for="wietab-2">Tab2 Content</label>

            <div class="wietabcontent">
                <p>
                    Tab2          
                </p>
            </div> 
        </div>

        <div class="wietab">
            <input type="radio" id="wietab-3" name="wietab-group-1">
            <label for="wietab-3">Tab3 Content Lang</label>

            <div class="wietabcontent">
                <p>
                    Tab3          
                </p>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/bt2py9q4/1/)

Comment: The same happens in the fiddle when you make the output pane narrower. So what is your goal? What _should_ happen on narrow screens?

Comment: I am not sure what possibilities there are, I see 2 options in my mind.
1. The tabs is under each other and content is 100%
2. The tabs scroll and contents is 100%

Comment: Have you tried implementing one of these?

Comment: No success yet.